# Cómo dar formato a números a decimales en datagridview usando vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, devexpress

Tengo un proyecto en vb.net donde en mi datagridview recive valores tipeados directo en las celadas. Ya esta en formato Numerico y N2 lo cual  da "#.##". Lo que pasa es cuando ingreso un valor ejemplo "120.45" me regresa de esta forma "12.045,00". Habria alguna forma de que con el punto "." me traiga de la primera forma. Hay algun formato de celdas ?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es problema del componente sino de la configuración de globalización de la pc, para que no te afecte, lo debes definir la región en las configuraciones iniciales. Te dejo un link con mas info.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bz9tc508(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN